# Jquery Mobile, Sencha Touch or

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, sencha-touch-2

I recently learnt there are Framworks that make single mobile apps to be developed for multiple platforms.

I just want some advice about which is the best framework to invest my time into learning.

And, can the apps generated be released in the various app stores or does the developer have to host the app independently?

I would appreciate the advice and direction.

Thanks

Comment: read this http://www.gajotres.net/sencha-touch-vs-jquery-mobile/

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch only supports Webkit-based browsers; jQuery mobile supports all browsers. Sencha Touch has great UI but jQuery mobile is like classic. Sencha Touch is all JS confusing to all, not easy to debug; jQuery mobile is like jQuery, Easy syntax, and has themeroller support so it has great CSS. For final thoughts: jQuery mobile is better than Sencha Touch because Sencha Touch is JS; you make an app using JS and it's confusing for first time mobile developers. So choose jQuery mobile.